How is numpy vectorization implemented?
Referring to Why is NumPy Fast?, it is said that vectorization can avoid for-loops.
So for example, addition of 2 ndarrays:
x1 = np.arange(0, 16).reshape(4, 4)
x2 = np.arange(17, 33).reshape(4, 4)
y = x1 + x2
print(y)

This prints:
array([[17, 19, 21, 23],
       [25, 27, 29, 31],
       [33, 35, 37, 39],
       [41, 43, 45, 47]])

So in this y = x1 + x2, right, there is no for-loop in this python program. And according to the above document, they are implemented in optimized C.
My question is, in the "optimized C", is there no for loop?
If no loop in C also, how is the vectorization implemented? I already know numpy ndarray's basic structure: single byte array, shape, strides, copy/view, etc.
I want to know the basic idea of how vectorization is implemented without for-loop, rather than implementation detail in a specific source code.

What they mean is "avoid Python for-loops".  There has to be a loop somewhere.  In SOME cases, the processors have vector instructions that can operate on multiple units at a time, but the data structure has to be exactly right for that to work.

And, as a side note, the ndarray you have above is not a byte array, it is an array of 64-bit integers.

There's nothing magically bad about 'for loops'. There's also nothing special about algorithms that use some form of loop (while, for, whatever), other than these algorithms needing to perform some operation repeatedly, dependent on data. The vectorisation in a library like numpy organises the data in a way where operations can be applied to it very efficiently - what that ends up being depends on the compute device and on how flexible the implementation is.  See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/glossary.html#term-vectorization

As others mentioned, there's nothing wrong with loops in C. It's Python that is slow, and writing fast Python code for number crunching usually revolves around writing as little Python as possible and letting the C code running behind the scenes in libraries like numpy, torch or pandas do the work instead. Regarding the "optimized C" term, that can involve a lot of strategies, SIMD instructions (which are probably where the term vectorization comes from in the numpy context) and parallel algorithms might be some of them.

@TimRoberts Numpy allocates array as a raw byte array and then can interpret it as a int64-based array. Users can also do that with np.view. It is just a reinterpret cast internally AFAIR.

Ah I see, "avoid Python for-loops" this makes sense. Thank you.

The purpose of numpy vectorization is to avoid Python for loops, on Python objects. The key to speed is the optimized underlying data structure. There are (most likely) loops involved in the low level numpy code, but they are much more efficient than Python loops.
In short, since you're mostly interested in the general idea, a numpy array has a more compact structure in the memory. The numeric data is contiguous and the metadata separate.
For example, you could see this 2D array as a "bag" of consecutive 64bits integers, with some metadata to explain what this represents in 2D (ND):
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
a.dtype
# dtype('int64')

a.shape
# (2, 2)

a.tobytes()
# b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

# now converting to unsigned 8bits
a.astype('uint8').tobytes()
# b'\x01\x02\x03\x04'

In contrast, the python equivalent [[1, 2], [3, 4]] is a nested structure of Python objects. In fact you have a list object that contains 2 list objects, that each contain two integer objects. Each of these objects is "self-aware", containing the methods used to perform their own operations, which adds overhead. If you imagine a larger example (100x100), then the python nested list takes up ~366kB of memory vs ~80kB for the numpy array (8*100*100 bytes + some extra bytes for the metadata).
The integer 1 takes 28 bytes in memory (only 8 for a 1 as int64 in numpy), making it slower to access, but it also handles the computation differently. When you add 1 + 2, python is going to call the objects __add__ method to perform the operation, which has a lot of overhead when repeated. Numpy integers are not "self-aware", numpy is taking care of the low level operation, identifying the correct strides of the input arrays, then performing the internal C-speed loops to iterate over the numbers ideally accessing them in a contiguous section of the memory.

Regarding the Python objects/lists, it is even worse in practice since lists contains not directly object but pointers to shared objects (dynamically reference-counted). This not only add an additional indirection but also a memory overhead (8 bytes per object reference on mainstream 64-bit machines). With integers, the reference is already often as big as the target integer in Numpy if not even bigger (for 32-bit which are rather maintream in Numpy on Windows). There is no benefit of doing that for integer since they are immutable. In practice, AFAIK, object caching can mitigate overheads.
